# How do I setup arquillian to test a maven war project by deploying the entire war to WildFly embedded?

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I 'd like to do macro (not micro!) black box testing of my war on an embedded WildFly instance.

My maven project looks like this

```
<project>
  ...
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <!-- Lots of classes in src/main/webapp and files in src/main/webapp -->
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Lots of compile/runtime dependencies that change very frequently -->
    <!-- Lots of test dependencies that change very frequently -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My arquillian tests need to fulfill the following requirements:

- **Deploy the entire war** to the app server in the tests. This includes all production classes, all runtime dependencies and all `src/main/webapp` files. From a maintenance perspective it's impossible to do micro deployments because class dependencies and jar dependencies change very frequently. So we cannot enumerate anything in the ShrinkWrap deployment.
- **Don't hardcode anything** in the test or arquillian.xml **that is already known by the maven `pom.xml`**. This includes version strings, dependency lists, package or class lists, app server installation directories, etc.
- **Don't use more than 1 maven module**. My tests to test my war belong in the test folder of the same maven module that produces the war.
- Users that checkout my code need to be able so simply run the tests:

  - **Tests needs to run from IntelliJ** after simply opening the `pom.xml` with IntelliJ.
  - Use WildFly embedded container, so nothing needs to be installed first, no process needs to be run first and definitely **no `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable needs to be set** first.
- I am only interested in black box testing, so all my tests can *run as client*.

In theory, this is all possible with Arquillian's Maven resolver,  embedded containers, `@RunAsClient`, maven failsafe plugin, some `arquillian.xml` magic and a lot of maven magic. But in practice, I cannot get that stuff to work together, nor do I find any documentation that covers this scenario decently, so I am hoping someone can clearly show how they can work together.

Comment: If you consider macro testing, you may take a look at [arquillian-suite-extension](https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension) or abandon Arquillian at all. Why? Because Arquillian is about a micro-deployments, and it seems that it's not the case for you. Also using embedded JEE App Servers is like [asking for troubles](http://arquillian.org/blog/2012/04/13/the-danger-of-embedded-containers/)...

Comment: Vanilla Arquillian should really support the features of arquillian-suite-extension out of the box!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely sounds like a case for ShrinkWrap Resolver [Maven Importer](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver#maven-importer)  (not to be confused with the Maven Resolver). [Here](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/maven/impl-maven-archive/src/test/java/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/impl/maven/archive/importer/WarMavenImporterTestCase.java) are some tests showing its usage.

I have a standalone sample for just a case of [Gradle Importer](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver#gradle-importer) ( I know you're using maven ), but the test construction is similiar [here](https://github.com/mmatloka/arquillian-gradle-sample/blob/master/single-module/src/test/java/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/example/FullGreeterTest.java#L21).

I don't have currenly a whole example publically available with both `@RunAsClient` and Maven Importer but I have a project using them together with `Graphene` and this combination do work :). Generally the test should look like:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SomeControllerIT {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class).loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importBuildOutput()
            .as(WebArchive.class);
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void shouldDoSth() throws Exception {
      ...
   }
}
```

Why to use Maven Importer instead of the war deployment? War is created after tests execution, this means that if the war exists during test execution, then it comes from previous build and is outdated.

Comment: Thanks, the importer works! I still get this: `[WARN  Failed to define class org.optaconf.service.ConferenceServiceArquillianTest in Module "deployment.optaconf-webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/optaconf/service/ConferenceServiceArquillianTest (Module "deployment.optaconf-webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader) ... Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/optaconf/service/AbstractArquillianTest`. Looks like the arquillian is still trying to add the test class to the wildfly classpath, even though it's a RunAsClient test?

Comment: Please try additionally with `@Deployment(testable = false)`

Comment: Many maven plugins are not supported with this method, so it's not guaranteed to work.